# Mock dependencies in Magento 2 integration tests

Tags: magento2, testing, dependency-injection, integration-test

Suppose the following scenario:

- I have a class that makes calls to an external service
- The class implements an interface and is defined as preferred implementation for this interface in `di.xml`
- A block receives this interface as constructor parameter
- I want to test a Magento request in an integration test that uses this block

I don't want to actually call the external service, so I would like to mock that class and wonder what's the best way to do so.

I know that you can define DI preferences on the fly with

```
$objectManager->configure(
    ['preferences' => [TheInterface::class => MockClass::class]]
);
```

but this requires defining a mock class `MockClass` yourself, I cannot use a PHPUnit mock object.

This works okay if the injected class is a factory because I can create a mock factory that creates the actual mock object.

But is this the only way or am I missing something?

**Update:**

The suggested method

```
$objectManager->addSharedInstance($mock, TheInterface::class);
```

looked good first, but only worked as long as there were *no* preferences defined. These take precedene over shared instances.

I tried to dynamically remove the preference:

```
$this->objectManager->configure(
    ['preferences' => [TheInterface::class => null]]
);
```

But unfortunately Magento calls `ltrim($to, '\\')` on the argument, which converts it to an empty string. This results in:

> ReflectionException: Class  does not exist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use \Magento\TestFramework\ObjectManager::addSharedInstance for this.

Example:

```
$objectManager->addSharedInstance($mock, TheInterface::class);
```

Comment: Works well if there is no preference set yet in `di.xml`, but the preference seems to have priority over the shared instance.

Comment: In this case you need  add shared interface for preferred class. for ex. if we have <preference for="Psr\Log\LoggerInterface" type="Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog" /> than you should add shared instance as $objectManager->addSharedInstance($mock, "Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog");

Comment: Nice, that worked!

Comment: Please note that if you want to mock a virtual type, you have to use the name of the virtual type, not the class name: `$this->objectManager->addSharedInstance($mockedLogger, 'CustomLogger');`. Knowing this would have saved me an hour :-P